# 2 and more keyboard layout groups in Linux changed by different hot keys

Tags: linux, xorg, keyboard-layout

So, this is something I've been dreaming of for years now. I've sporadically foraged for a solution on Google but never really found anything. I was told once by someone on IRC that it's possible but never really seen how this could be done.

Here's what I want.

I use en and ru keyboard layouts as two primary languages of input that I work with on a daily basis. I use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Caps_Lock</kbd> to toggle these layouts. Sometimes I need to type in ua and pl, and I want to have them in a separate group of layouts that would be toggled by pressing say <kbd>L_Win</kbd>+<kbd>Caps_Lock</kbd>.

So, whenever I press <kbd>L_Win</kbd>+<kbd>Caps_Lock</kbd> I start cycling between ua and pl, and when I need to get back to my standard group of en and ru I would press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Caps_Lock</kbd>.

This description is in no way linked to any real understanding of how the existing keyboard layout switching framework works. It's just me imagining the ideal scenario.

Well, dear super users,  can this be done on Linux? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

I made a little improvement for this script. Now it doesn't break WM keyboard switcher. It works a little different as TS wants but I think it is more convinient this way at least for me

You should change keyboard model and options if you want

```
#!/bin/sh
current=`setxkbmap -query | grep layout|cut  -d ',' -f 2`
if [ "$current" == 'pl' ]
then 
    notify-send -t 1500 -i keyboard "Keyboard layouts: EN / RU"
    setxkbmap -model logitech_base -layout en,ru -variant , -option grp:caps_toggle,compose:rwin
else 
    notify-send -t 1500 -i keyboard "Keyboard layouts: UA / PL"
    setxkbmap -model logitech_base -layout ua,pl -variant , -option grp:caps_toggle,compose:rwin
fi
```

Comment: It looks like you're never going to get out of EN/RU group, because once you're in UA/PL, you go into EN/RU and you're stuck there forever. PS: maybe not ;D

Comment: Well, I have CapsLock as a groop switcher. It switches between EN/RU. When I need UA/PL I run that script (mapped to CTRL+Caps) and use Caps to switch between UA/PL. Another Ctrl+Caps restore layouts to EN/RU.

Actually I use it only for 3 langs: EN/RU and EN/UA groups.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would probably be to use your window manager's keyboard layout switcher for your main layouts (en and ru) and then use the following script mapped to <kbd>L_Win</kbd>+<kbd>Caps_Lock</kbd>:

```
#!/bin/bash 

current=`setxkbmap -query | grep layout | fold -s2 | tail -n 1`
if [ "$current" == 'ua' ]
then
    setxkbmap -layout pl
else
    setxkbmap -layout ua
fi
```

If you save the script as `toggle_layout.sh`, make it executable and map it to your desired keybord shortcut using your window manager's tools, it should do what you need. The script just checks if you are currently using the `ua` layout and, if not, switches to `pl`.

---

UPDATE:

I got it to work in the following way:

1. Map the script above to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> (that's keypad `8`).
2. Make another script to toggle between the main layouts:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash 

   current=`setxkbmap -query | grep layout | fold -s2 | tail -n 1`
   if [ "$current" == 'en' ]
   then
       setxkbmap -layout ru
   else
       setxkbmap -layout en
   fi
   ```
3. Map the script from step 2 to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> (that's keypad `2`).

Make sure you use keys that do not change when the layout changes (that's why I used the keypad in this example). I don't know if you can do this without breaking the WM native way of changing layouts but at least this should work.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. I'll give that a try. Nonetheless, I'm really curious if this can be done by simply configuring existing standard software (like xorg-xkbutils/GNOME).

Comment: @ILIV, AFAIK, it is not possible to set two different keyboard shortcuts for keyboard switching. All I am using here is the standard `setxkbmap`. I doubt you can get it any simpler than that.

Comment: Yep, it's a pretty good solution -- that I have to test yet lol -- and  I'm almost ashamed that I didn't think of that myself! I was just too focused on doing it by configuring xkbutils/DE. I'm actually so excited that you responded, because if this works well this is a dream come true :P

Comment: Here's the problem with your approach. Once I run setxkbmap in terminal, I lose any keyboard layouts but one that I passed as an argument to -layout option.

Comment: @ILIV, you're quite right, it seems to break the WM's native method of changing layouts. See my updated answer for a workaround. It works fine on my LMDE machine when switching between el,es,en and ua.

Comment: That's what I thought of doing myself, actually :) It feels as a hack, though, and it breaks DE/WM configuration. Not too good, but, of course, if you really need it like myself this is better than nothing at all :) Maybe I should talk to folks behind xkbutils, they must be extremely knowledgeable in this topic!

Comment: I sent a message to Xorg mailing list yesterday, and here's the answer that I've got, but I haven't tested it yet. I post this link here so that anyone interested in the topic could benefit from seeing the reply: http://lists.x.org/archives/xorg/2012-November/055066.html

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution, based on the ones already provided.

Bind it to a key and provide desired layouts as arguments:

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>: `keyboard-keyout-switch en,ua en,ru`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e

if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]; then
  echo 'Expected at least 2 arguments, specifying layout groups to switch.'
  echo 'Got:' "$@"
  exit 1
fi

declare -a groups
groups=( "$@" )

current=$( setxkbmap -query | grep layout | cut  -d ':' -f 2 | tr -d ' ' )

for currentI in "${!groups[@]}"; do
  if [[ "${groups[$currentI]}" = "$current" ]]; then
    nextI=$(( (currentI + 1) % ${#groups[@]} ))
    notify-send -t 1500 -i keyboard "Layout: ${groups[nextI]}" || true
    setxkbmap -layout "${groups[nextI]}"
    exit 0
  fi
done

echo 'Currently active layout is not preset in the configuration.'
echo 'Current layout:' "$current"
echo 'Configuration layouts:' "${groups[@]}"
exit 1
```